# Why can't I delete any character?

Tags: eve-online

I have 3 characters on my Eve Online Account:

- Main Char
- CEO for my Corp
- Neutral Scout

[image]

I want to delete the Scout since he has no trained skills at all and I don't need him anymore. But there is no delete button for any of my characters. The skull symbol that used to be there is gone. Can anyone answer why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know if you are having the same problem as I did.
But I found I could not delete a character via the 'terminate' icon also. But I could **right click on his portrait when he was in the 'selected' position and terminate from the pop up menu.**

Comment: Dang, that's embarrassing.... :D There used to be a skull button, now it is rightclick only..